# Not getting the required output in my merge sort

Tags: java, sorting

Here is my merge sort implementation in java and i am not getting the sorted output. For sorting which sort is best merger or quick sort.
Code:

```
public void sort(ArrayList<Integer> finalarray)
    {   
        if(finalarray.size()<2) return;

        int mid;

        mid = finalarray.size()/2;

        ArrayList<Integer> right = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> left  = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<mid;i++) left.add(finalarray.get(i));
        for(int i=mid;i<finalarray.size();i++) right.add(finalarray.get(mid));
        sort(left);
        sort(right);
        //System.out.println("Left" + left.size());
        //System.exit(1);
        int  l=0 ,f=0, r=0;
        while(l<left.size() && r<right.size()) {
             if(right.get(r)>left.get(l)) {
                 finalarray.set(f, left.get(l));             
                 l++;
             } else {
                 finalarray.set(f, right.get(r));
                 r++;
             }
             f++;               
        }
        while(l<left.size()) 
            finalarray.set(f, left.get(l));
            f++;
            l++:
        }
        while( r<right.size())  {
            finalarray.set(f, right.get(r));
            f++;
            r++:
        }
    }
}
```

The final output is not a sorted array please help me to found out where i have done mistakes. Array which is printed is not sorted
Thanks in advance

Comment: Learn how to use debugging tools. Try to debug your code step by step. When you will find unresolvable problem - return to SO again.

Comment: Do you have to create your own implementation?
If not, you can use `Collections.sort()` method.

Comment: @J.Lucky i have to create my own implementation

Answer (score 1):

After one array is exhausted you iterate the reminder, but there is a bug in it:

```
    while(l<left.size() )
    {
        finalarray.set(f, right.get(l));
                         //^^^
              f++;
               l++:
    }
```

You should fill it with element from `left`, not from `right`.